# How to write to /sys/ with a script after rebooting? (sudo)

Tags: sudo, brightness

I'm trying to write to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` and read from `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` from a script I wrote. The problem is it requires root, and even if I `chown` or `chmod` it, the permissions reset after reboot.

I saw a solution to add something like:

```
user ALL = NOPASSWD: /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

using `visudo` but it doesn't work. What other options do I have?

Comment: The file ownership and/or permissions of your script that you set  by _chown_ and _chmod_ change on reboot?  Where in your file system is the script located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files in `/sys` are not physical files on disk.  They are virtual files that let you access information in your active kernel.  The practical impact of that is that running `chown`, `chmod`, etc. on them is an ephemeral operation, as you have discovered.  The entire filesystem view in `/sys` is generated by the kernel when the system boots, so there's no way to make persistent changes.

The easiest solution is to run your *script* as root.  Using `sudo` is a common solution.  You would need to give your user the ability to run your script as root.  So, for example, if your script is installed as `/usr/local/bin/configure-brightness`, you could create `/etc/sudoers.d/brightness` with the following content:

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/configure-brightness
```

This file (`/etc/sudoers.d/brightness`) must be owned by `root` and have mode `440`.

With this configuration in place, you can run:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/configure-brightness
```

...and the script will run as `root`, which means it will be able to read from/write to files in `/sys`.